Finding functions that satisfy $\left|f(x) - f(y)\right| = \left|x - y\right|$ and $\left|f(x) + f(y)\right| = \left|x + y\right|$.
I’m trying to find functions $f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy these conditions:

$\ |f(x) - f(y)| = |x - y|$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$.
$\ |f(x) + f(y)| = |x + y|$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$.

I’ve tried analyzing distance-preserving properties and found that $f(x) = x$ and $f(x) = -x$ could be solutions, but I'm unsure how to fully prove this. How can I rigorously demonstrate that these are the only possible solutions?

Hint:  Start by showing that $f(0)=0$.

when $y=x$
$$|f(x)+f(y)|=|x+y| \implies |f(x)|=|x|$$

Can we solve it using system resolution and reasoning by case disjunction?

Note that it follows from the reasoning in WW1's comment that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=-x$, which implies that $f(x)=x$ for all $x$ or $f(x)=-x$ for all $x$. To see this, assume that there are $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x,\,f(y)=-y$. Then:
$$|x+y|=|f(x)+f(y)|=|x-y|$$
By squaring both sides, $x^2+2xy+y^2=x^2-2xy+y^2$, hence $x=0$ or $y=0$, implying that either $f(x)=-x=x=0$ or $f(y)=y=-y=0$. Therefore, $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=-x$ are the only possible solutions. As they are obviously solutions, we're done.

Thank you very much
